# IXmlSerializable and Root Element Prefix

Tags: xmlserializer, prefix, ixmlserializable

I have looked everywhere and not a single response is valid or the question is just slightly off to the point of not getting me the answer I need.   Given all the searches I have looked for there seems to be one MASSIVE flaw in .Net's implementation of xml serialization.

Default:

```
[XmlRoot("root", Namespace="http://myclass.org/")]
public class MyClass 
{
}

void Main() {
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
  XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  xsn.Add("mc", "http://myclass.org/");
  ser.Serialize(new StreamWriter(Console.Out), new MyClass(), xsn);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mc:root xmlns:mc="http://myclass.org/">
</mc:root>
```

IXmlSerializable:

```
[XmlRoot("root", Namespace="http://myclass.org/")]
public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
{
   public XmlSchema GetSchema() {return null;}
   public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {}
   public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {}
}

void Main() {
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
  XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  xsn.Add("mc", "http://myclass.org/");
  ser.Serialize(new StreamWriter(Console.Out), new MyClass(), xsn);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://myclass.org/">
</root>
```

WHY!

How do we fix this?

This is essential to figure out because without custom processing I will be forced to double step it, and process the serialized xml into an XmlDocument to fix this glitch.  and yes, this HAS to be a glitch.  I can work around everything else EXCEPT the root element.

I am not the only one who needs to know how to do this.

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Comment: 1) What is the problem exactly?  These two XML samples are semantically identical.  In both cases you have an element `root` in namespace `"http://myclass.org/"`.  In one case it is a prefixed namespace, in the other it is the default namespace - but the meaning is the same  2) Can you share the full source code for your `ReadXml()` and `WriteXml()` methods?

Comment: 1) Already declared in original post:  The class XmlSerializer produces different "anal-retentive" xml based upon whether IXmlSerializable IS implemented and
2) NOT how it is implemented.  I'm saying copy the code in the post direct, and run it.  There is no implementation in ReadXml/WriteXml, and it wouldn't matter if there was because the output XML is different based upon the presence of the interface, not it's implementation.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this problem?